# Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'out= 2017-07-11 at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime

```
$qu3 = 'UPDATE logs SET out= '.date("Y-m-d H:i:s").' WHERE sl_no= '.$sno;

  $r4 = mysql_query($qu3)or die(mysql_error());
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'out= 2017-07-11 23:04:52 WHERE sl_no= 73' at line 1

Comment: Strings need to be quoted. You shouldn't use `mysql_` anymore... or assuming your mysql and PHP are in the same timezone `out= now() WHERE `

Comment: and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Additionally `out` is reserved, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html. You need to backtick that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql